# Why is my Style Sheet Going HayWire on MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on familiarizing myself with the MVC on ASP.NET.  I have on my global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute("Dept", "Dept/Invoice/{Category}/{Name}", 
new {controller = "Dept", action = "Invoice", Category = "", Name = ""});
```

The Controller.cs code gets the data and put it in a table which is fine.  My html starts...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BMICPolicy.Dept>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/Test.css" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Style Sheet -

```
body
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Book Antiqua, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
     text-align: -moz-center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
table 
{
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;  
}

table td 
{
  padding: 5px;   
  border: solid 1px #000000;  
}

table th
{
  padding: 6px 5px;  
  background-color: #729FCB; 
  border: solid 1px #000000;   
  text-align: center;
}

thead
{
    /*font-size: medium;*/
    font: large, bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I am not sure why the Style sheet only works when I enter up to "Category" and my style sheet is completely disregarded when I type the name in the address bar (Body font style, table, td, th, thead, etc...).  Am I missing something?

Comment: I made the chane to clarify the going nuts... and my style sheet is included

Comment: Are you sure when you enter a name you don't get a 404 in your server logs for the stylesheet request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`../../Content/Test.css` is a relative URI, and means "look for a folder called `Content` in the parent folder of the parent folder of the current location, and in that folder find a file called `Test.css`.

When you only enter a category, you're looking for a sibling of the `Dept` folder called `Content`. When you enter a name as well, you're looking for a sibling of the `Invoice` folder.

Perhaps you want to use `/Content/Test.css` as the path to your stylesheet instead.

Comment: Use Url.Content to reference the css.  Don't use hardcoded path, because it will break if you publish the site under a subfolder of the root.  Url.Content handles this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your current path is treated as a nested folder hierarchy and the relative path simply does not work (your css is being search for in `Dept/Invoice/Content/Test.css` or something like this, which is obviously incorrect). This is a common situation with style and script files, especially when they are placed in the master page.

The right thing to do in this situation is to use `Url.Content` as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951577/how-to-include-js-files-in-asp-net-mvc-and-have-a-valid-path-on-all-routes).
Imho this works better than an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

`<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content`/Test.css" />

to this :

`<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Content/Test.css`") %>" />