# File Dialog Does Not Show Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I've been facing this problem for the past couple of days. I have an input of type "file" inside a tooltip. When I click on the button to open the file dialog, nothing shows up. Now I tried to use [Valums AJAX Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) and the same thing happens. The problem is there aren't any errors so I do not know how I can debug to find out what the problem is... Here's my code:

```
<div class="liImageThumb tooltip-trigger">
    <div class="tooltip down">
        <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
            <p class="liUploadButton greenButton">Upload</p>
            <p class="okButton"></p>           
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fileuploader.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var greenButton = $('.liUploadButton')[0];
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: greenButton,
            action: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Item")' //outputs the correct DOM node
        });
        console.log(greenButton);
    });
```

And here's the code that builds up the tooltip:

```
$('.tooltip-trigger').removeClass('nonjs').live('mouseover', function(){
        var $trigger = $(this);
        var $tooltip = $('.tooltip',$trigger);
        if (!$trigger.data('init')){
            $trigger.data('init', true);
            if($tooltip.length){
                $trigger.hoverIntent({
                    'over':function(){$tooltip.show();},
                    'out':function(){$tooltip.hide();},
                    'timeout':200
                });
                $trigger.trigger('mouseover');
            }
        }
    });
```

What do you think is preventing the dialog box from showing up?

Comment: Can you give us a jsbin? Hard to tell just from looking at this.

Comment: @Oscar Godson: Sorry but what do you mean by a jsbin? I'm not really good at javascript...

Comment: JSBin.com allows you to share your JS and code with us. We then can edit it and send you a link back with the code fixed. Just get the code you gave us above working as its working on your site now, but do it on JS bin :)

Comment: @Oscar Godson: it works on jsbin! Could it be some other code intercepting with the open dialog event? What could prevent the dialog from opening anyway?! Check it out: http://jsbin.com/iduxu5/edit

Answer (score -1):

Are you using this in ASP.Net MVC project ? I assume, you are, based on the `Url.Content` syntax.
If yes, your script tags `src` attribute should look like

```
src='<%=Url.Content("~/Content/script/MyFile.js")%>'
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951577/how-to-include-js-files-in-asp-net-mvc-and-have-a-valid-path-on-all-routes) answer for details.