# my javascript works locally but not on the server why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I know it is a silly question but my javascript works on very good locally, but on a some.com hosting server it doesn't work at all. Can any one please help me to figure it out my mistake?

Here is my javascript links:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Library/Client/Js/Utility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Library/Client/js/TlBarAction.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Library/Client/Js/ControlsFunc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Library/Client/Js/Menu.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: you sure your all script files has been located well on your file server ?

Comment: It's highly likely that its a server problem

Comment: Please define "doesn't work"

Comment: make sure you have uploaded all the files on server and folder hierarchy is same as of local.

Comment: Use the browser tools to double check why your files are not loaded.

Comment: @Ahmed Kamal, If you are using MVC following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951577/how-to-include-js-files-in-asp-net-mvc-and-have-a-valid-path-on-all-routes

Comment: @Ahmed Kamal If you are running with Firefox view the page source and check the js path.

Comment: check the console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Folder inside your project configuration path then no need to give like this `../../`

If your Folder inside your project just use like this `src="~/Library/Client/Js/Utility.js"`

If your Folder Outside of folder your project `src="../Library/Client/Js/Utility.js"` (one Folder)

as per the folder count you have to add `../`

Check Your Some.Com IIS Configuration whether the  js path correctly configured or not.

Hope this may helpful.,

Comment: thanx all for all your replies but i've tried everthing you guys said before but it still not working cause the javascript should loop all the Linkbuttons and there switch case but the linkbutton id cames diffrent and i don't know if it is the problem or not

Comment: @Ahmed Kamal provide your sample code here.we will try to figure it out.,

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your paths are correct, is your server case-sensitive?  Your code has three "JS" (capital "J") and one "js" (lowercase "j") references.

This will work fine, as is on a non-case-sensitive OS like Windows but may NOT work on a case-sensitive OS.

Comment: thanx all for all your replies but i've tried everthing you guys said before but it still not working cause the javascript should loop all the Linkbuttons and there switch case but the linkbutton id cames diffrent and i don't know if it is the problem or not

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in the root folder of your site then using ../ on a shared hosting server is not allowed as it breaks you out of your container.  You need to make sure that you have your scripts within your root and then use ~/ or just the folder name accordingly.  If you are not in your root folder then you can use ~/ but only if your website is being hosted as its own application and not just a subdirectory.

I would suggest trying Library/Client/Js/Utility.js first, then /Library/Client/Js/Utility.js and then ~/Library/Client/Js/Utility.js to see which works.