# How to add Js file for a aspx page in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a set of aspx page & its associated controller. now i want to add a js file for a aspx page. i'm not getting how to add and link to particular aspx page in MVC.

what is the easiest way to add and link for the particular aspx page.

**Edit**

i created a folder inside Scripts-->Views-->Controllername-->somejsfile.js file.

in site master, below the jquery scripts loading place, i added

```
<script src="/Scripts/Views/ControllerName/somejsfile.js?Version=<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScriptVersion"]%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now i have added init function inside js like

```
var somejsfileNamescript= function () {
    return {

        Init: function () {

            alert("Hello");

        }
    }
} ();
```

I want this to get executed when the page is loaded. This is the only one js file present in my application
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include js files in asp.net MVC and have a valid path on all routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951577/how-to-include-js-files-in-asp-net-mvc-and-have-a-valid-path-on-all-routes)

Comment: But how do i link to a perticualar aspx page, lets take i have 5 aspx page with name index.aspx. Now i want to attach js file for a single aspx out of 5. how to do?

Comment: In mvc you will not directly link to aspx page instead you have to create link for the route. Your question is still not clear. Please edit it and describe your problem well.

Comment: i have edited, please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is that simple, in your master file add a `<script>` block and use the jquery `$(document).ready()` function to init the script. (Assuming you are using jquery)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    somejsfileNamescript.Init();
});
</script>
```